# Gulp Watch não atualiza

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulpjs

Olá, sou iniciante em `GULP` e estou com o seguinte problema, o codigo abaixo, que simplemente minifica o `JS` e o `CSS`, funciona perfeitamente se rodar as funções no `default` e rodar o `GULP`. O problema é que com o `Watch` ele não funciona, ele cria o arquivo mas em branco.

Ja respondendo algumas perguntas:

- Sim, ele é iniciado corretamente, ou seja, o `GULP` detecta a mudança no arquivo e executa a função.
- Sim, no `default` ele minifica corretamente.
- Sim, caso não possua o arquivo minificado, ele cria, ou seja, ele entra na função, mas por algum motivo ele não consegue ler o `CSS`/`JS` quando a função é chamada pelo `Watch`.

Código abaixo:

```
var css = [
    './css/estilo.css'
];
var js  = [
    './js/app.js'
];

var gulp = require('gulp');
var jsmin = require('gulp-jsmin');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin");
var stripCssComments = require('gulp-strip-css-comments');

gulp.task('minify-css', function(){
    gulp.src(css)  
        .pipe(stripCssComments({all: true}))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/min/'));
});

gulp.task('minify-js', function () {
    gulp.src(js)
        .pipe(jsmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/min/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(js, ['minify-js']);
    gulp.watch(css, ['minify-css']);
});
```

Já tentei declarar o caminho do `CSS` diretamente na função ao invés de chamar a variável `CSS`. Já tentei também declarar a variável como global, mas nada disso muda o resultado que é o arquivo em branco.

Answer (score 1):

Modifica teu arquivo js e css

`./js/app.js` para `/js/app.js`

`./css/estilo.css` para `/css/estilo.css`

ele procura um executavel como esse `./css/estilo.css.js` , daí como ele não encontra ele coloca tudo em branco

por via das dúvidas tenta inverter a ordem

```
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(js, ['minify-js']);
    gulp.watch(css, ['minify-css']);
});
```

para

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
        gulp.watch(js, ['minify-js']);
        gulp.watch(css, ['minify-css']);
    });
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sou muito avançado no quesito `Gulp`, mas, assim como em `Grunt`, por exemplo, o método `default` é apenas o nome do processo a ser chamado. Com isso você pode criar uma lista de tarefas.

Por exemplo, suponhamos que hoje você vai trabalhar exclusivamente com as funções em `JS`, logo você não precisa minificar os arquivos `css`. Para isso você poderia chamar a task `onlyjs`, por exemplo:

```
gulp.task('onlyjs', ['minify-js']);
```

Já se você for trabalhar somente com `css`, poderia ser a task `onlycss`:

```
gulp.task('onlycss', ['minify-css']);
```

No seu código atual você não esta chamando a `task` e sim a declaração da mesma.

Mas note que não há problema algum em você continuar chamando a `task:'default'`, pois esse é o comportamento padrão. Partindo do mesmo exemplo anterior, você poderia chamar apenas a minificação de `JS` e continuar com um `Watch` (que neste caso iria expandir para o `css` também).

```
gulp.task('onlyjs', ['minify-js','watch']);
```

Mas caso queira uma `task` que se chame `Watch` e não faça a minificação assim que chamada, basta criar uma nova `task`, assim:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['watch']);
```

*Nota*: Atualmente trabalho mais com `Grunt` então pode ser que alguma regra de declaração tenha mudado, mas a ideia geral é essa.

Comment: Acho que voce não entendeu minha pergunta, o problema não é a chamada, ao alterar o .css, ele altera o .min, o problema que ele altera e deixa ele em branco. Caso não tenha arquivo css, ele cria um, ou seja, ele entra na função minify-css, só que ele deixa o arquivo em branco. Isso apenas quando é atualizado pelo watch, quando roda a função pelo default, ela funciona sem problemas.

Comment: @VictorDitadi Mas rodando pelo default, ele não mantém o watch?

Comment: Ele funciona no default, porem no watch, sempre que eu salvo o estilo.css, o estilo.min.css fica em branco, por algum motivo ele apaga o que ja ta la dentro

Comment: @VictorDitadi Uma coisa que notei em alguns exemplos, eles possuem `return` nas `tasks` do js e css, por exemplo. Tente definir assim: `gulp.src(css)` -> `return gulp.src(css)` e no JS `return gulp.src(js)` (isso na declaração das respectivas tasks, não no watch).